# SoapUI 4.5.1 Pro: I can not save the request

Tags: xml, xsd, soapui

I use the SoapUI Pro 4.5.1 and I have one problem.
My request contains a empty value

```
<aa1: parameter1></parameter1>
```

I get the correct response from the service. Then I close current request and perform another request. Then again I open the first request (xml-bookmark). But the first query contains data:

```
<aa1: parameter1 xsi:nil="true"/>
```

I have to pass a null value, not zero.
Why is the change?
Thanks!

Comment: I changed "true" to "false" --> File --> Save All Projects. It did not help. Value "true" is saved.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due your request XML schema in the WSDL. If you check the `xsd` probably your element is defined as:

```
<xs:element name="parameter1" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

The goal of the `nillable` attribute [from documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/) is:

> ...the **absence of an element does not have any particular meaning**: It
>   may indicate that the information is unknown, or not applicable, or
>   the element may be absent for some other reason. *Sometimes it is
>   desirable to represent an unshipped item, unknown information, or
>   inapplicable information _explicitly_ with an element*, rather than by an
>   absent element.

If a node element has a `nillable=true` attribute in `xsd` declaration then it's allowed to have a *`xsi:nil` in the XML when this element is empty*.

[From the documentation:](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)

> Any `xsi:nil` attribute on the element obeys the rules. The element is
>   allowed to have an `xsi:nil` attribute only if the element is declared
>   `nillable`, and `xsi:nil = 'true'` is allowed only if the element itself
>   is empty.

#### Summarized

SOAPUI is inferring this for you and it's changing the element since it's an empty element and probably is declared in the `xsd` as a `nillable`. If you want to avoid this you can change your WSDL to remove the `nillable=true` attribute from this element, and reload the WSDL in the SOAPUI project. Or if your WS is well implemented don't worry about that since probably the response is correct in both cases.